# overload a copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering about the concept of copy constructor and the concept was rather clear.Can any one show me how to overload a copy constructor in C++.

Comment: You mean *override* the default one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A copy constructor is simple a constructor which takes a reference to another instance of the same type.  It must have one of the following signatures:

```
 MyClass( const MyClass& other );
 MyClass( MyClass& other );
 MyClass( volatile const MyClass& other );
 MyClass( volatile MyClass& other );
```

You can implement all four of them if you like, though I don't think a copy constructor which takes a non-const reference makes much sense.

Comment: It can also have any number of extra parameters, as long as those parameters have default values.

Comment: Can I use two of them in one class (just to clarify your answer). In other words can a class has 2 copy c-tors?

Comment: With different signatures yes.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Yes, you can.  You may get an informational warning, but it is allowed.

Comment: @Prætorian: Yes, *but* beware... some compilers don't treat a copy constructor with extra arguments in the same way. IBM compiler, for example, will fail to elide copies if the copy constructor has extra defaulted arguments...

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Also, I don't think it makes a lot of sense to take a non-const reference when the entire idea is that you are simply making a copy of the argument.

Comment: @EdS. Another thing - it shall be non template constructor to serve as copy c-tor.

Comment: @EdS. That was why bad things in C++11 happened to `std::auto_ptr`

Comment: Can you make it a bit clear with an example where it gets overloaded

Comment: @Robᵩ: An example of what exactly?  I said it doesn't make sense logically as you should not be mutating your argument in a copy constructor.  Of course it works.

Comment: @EdS. An "example where it gets overloaded", as user1301449 requested.

Comment: can we override a copy constructor.overloading is working fine